# Full web app utilizing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having started a new software dev role recently I'm in the process of developing my first full web app project using the following stack HTML + CSS + JavaScript + PHP.

I'm new in terms of applying these lessons I have learnt in the recent past in each language (as you might see from my basic sounding earlier questions) and I was wondering if I'm so far I'm adhering to the best possible practices in terms of developing the UI bits of the project.

I'm aware of numerous articles/tutorials which can guide me but advice from any experienced individual here on S/Overflow I feel would be equally valuable.

My first development objective is to achieve the development of a registration page which serves as the landing page. In simple terms the design is as follows:

- A navigation bar running at the top
- A welcome message section
- An image and text carousel with an automatic slideshow
- Facebook and Google registration buttons.
- A registration form
- A footer bar

Below is my HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

   <title>Sign Up or Log In</title>

   <!-- Generic CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/public.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Social networking log in button CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/auth-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css&2.6.0/build/base/base-min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

   <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom CSS -->
   <link href="stylesheets/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Custom Fonts -->
   <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- HTML5 Reset Stylesheet
   <link href="stylesheets/html5reset-1.6.1.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

   <!-- Normalize CSS
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/normalize.css" />  -->    

   <script type="js/htmlfivepatterns.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav id="topbar"> 
        <a id="logo_link" href="">Sign Up or Log In</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">LOG IN</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>ABOUT US</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Welcome message -->
    <section class="welcome_message">Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... Welcome message ... </section>

    <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest1.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <a class="carousel_caption" href="#">Caption A</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest2.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <a class="carousel_caption" href="#">Caption B</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('images/1900x1080imgtest3.jpg');"></div>

                <div class="carousel-caption">
                     <a class="carousel_caption" href="#">Caption C</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <section id="page_content" class="page_content_div">

        <div class="page_content_main_div">

            <div class="sign_up_div_option">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-facebook large" href="#">Sign up with <b>Facebook</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="sign_up_div_option">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-google large" href="#">Sign up with <b>Google</b></a>
            </div>

            <hr class="hr"></hr>

            <form id="register_form_id" name="registration_form" action="#" method="POST" class="sign_up_form" >
                <div class="sign_up_heading_div">
                    <p>Or sign up with e-mail:</p>
                </div>

                <div class="sign_up_notification_div">
                    <span id="sign_up_notification_id"></span>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter first name" id="firstname_id" name="firstname" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required placeholder="Enter first name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter second name" id="secondname_id" name="secondname" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required placeholder="Enter second name">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter an email" id="email_id" name="email" type="text" required placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>

                <div>
                    <input title="Enter a password" id="password_id" name="password" type="password" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" required placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>                

                <div>
                    <input title="Re-enter password" id="reenterpassword_id" name="reenterpassword" type="password" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" required placeholder="Re-enter password">
                </div>

                <div class="form_button_internal_div">
                    <button title="Type your second name" type="submit" class="btn_sign_up">Sign Up</button>
                </div>

                <div class="form_terms_of_service_internal_div">
                    <p class="terms_of_service">By signing up, I agree to the <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Terms of Service</b></a> and <a href='#' id="generic_link_decoration"><b>Privacy Policy</b></a>.</p>
                </div>                                
            </form>

        </div>
    </section>      

    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal_header">

            <div class="modal_title">Sign up or Log In</div>
          </div>

          <div class="modal_body">

            <div class="log_in_div_option_a">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-facebook large" href="#">Log in with <b>Facebook</b></a>
            </div>

            <div class="log_in_div_option_b">
                <a class="btn-auth btn-google large" href="#">Log in with <b>Google</b></a>
            </div>

            <hr class="hr"></hr>

            <p class="log_in_div_option_c">Or log in using your e-mail</p>

            <div class="log_in_notification_div">
                <span id="log_in_notification_id"></span>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input title="Enter username" id="log_in_firstname_id" class="log_in_firstname" name="log_in_firstname" type="text" required placeholder="Enter e-mail">
            </div>

            <div>
                <input title="Enter password" id="log_in_firstname_id" class="log_in_enterpassword" name="log_in_enterpassword" type="password" required placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>         
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn_close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn_log_in">Log In</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section>
        <footer class="footer_div"> 
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>TERMS OF SERVICE</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>FEATURES</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>HELP</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </footer>    
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="stylesheets/bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel i.e. directly related to carousel class name -->
    <script>
        $('.carousel').carousel( {
            interval: 3500 //changes the speed
        })

        document.registration_form.firstname.onfocus=function() {
            var validate_firstname = document.getElementById('firstname_id').value;

            if (validate_firstname == null || validate_firstname == " " || validate_firstname == "") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "(Please enter first name)";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "";
            }                                                 
        }

        document.registration_form.secondname.onfocus=function() {

            var validate_secondname = document.getElementById('secondname_id').value;

            if (validate_secondname == null || validate_secondname == " " || validate_secondname == "") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "(Please enter second name)";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "";
            }
        }

        document.registration_form.email.onfocus=function() {

            var validate_email = document.getElementById('email_id').value;

            if (validate_email == null || validate_email == " " || validate_email == "") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "(Please enter e-mail)";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "";
            }               
        }

        document.registration_form.password.onfocus=function() {

            var validate_password = document.getElementById('password_id').value;

            if (validate_password == null || validate_password == " " || validate_password == "") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "(Please enter password)";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "";
            }
        }

        document.registration_form.password.onfocus=function() {

            var validate_reenter_password = document.getElementById('reenterpassword_id').value;

            if (validate_reenter_password == null || validate_reenter_password == " " || validate_reenter_password == "") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "(Please re-enter password)";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "";
            }         
        }

        // Use onchange to find out if @ is part of user entered e-mail
        /*document.registration_form.email.onchange=function() {
            var userEnteredEmail = document.registration_form.email.value;

            if(email.indexOf("@")) {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "Invalid e-mail"; // value in '' is name of element which will display the error message
            }
        }

        // Use onblur to find out if @ is part of user entered e-mail
        document.registration_form.email.onblur=function() {
            if(document.registration_form.email.value="") {
                document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id').innerHTML = "Please enter e-mail"; // value in '' is name of element which will display the error message
            }
        }*/
    </script>     

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I will comment on the JavaScript only.

Each of your change handlers are doing essentially the same thing: check if the field is null, a single space, or the empty string and add a message to a notification panel.

The textbox text attribute will not return a null -- only empty string. I assume in checking for a single space you are invalidating whitespace values. As written however, a double space ("  ") would validate. I'm not familiar with the YUI library, but given its prevalence would be quite surprised if it did not contain dim sort of `isNullOrWhitespace` utility method.

The same notification area  appears to be updated each time, but is looked up each time. Only the message is different. I would suggest the following factory method:

```
var notificationArea = document.getElementById('sign_up_notification_id');

function fieldValidator (field, invalidMessage) {
    return function () {
        if (isNullOrWhitespace(field.value)
        notificationArea.innerHTML = invalidMessage;
    };
}
```

Where `isNullOrWhitespace` is the utility mentioned above, and use it like this:

```
document.registration_form.firstname.onfocus = fieldValidator (document.getElementById('firstname_id'), "(Please enter first name)");
```